# display backslashes as array values

Tags: php, arrays

I wanna have an array like the following:

```
$my_array = array("\", "\\");
```

But the elements in my array cause problems because the slashes are considered as escape characters. How do I create a PHP array that contains those elements please?

Comment: `array("\\", "\\\\");` will produce the array `["\", "\\"]`.  \ is an escape character, so if you want a literal backslash, you need to escape it: \\

Answer (score 1):

You are to duble them:

```
$my_array = array("\\\\", "\\");
print_r($my_array);
```

So that the seeing two slashes the second one is written. In case of double slashes you are to make 4 of them.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you're escaping the last double-quote in your first element. It thinks that you're trying to escape `"`, not ending the element. You could use double-slashes (to escape the escape).

Your first element isn't closed as an element, and second element will contain `\` in your example.

```
$my_array = array("\\", "\\\");
```

This will have `\` in the first element and `\\` in the second.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`).

Answer (score 0):

It might make the code more readable to create a `const BS` (for **B**ack **S**lash) constant to make the array more readable.

```
const BS = '\\';

$ar = array(BS, BS . BS);

foreach ($ar as $val) {
   echo $val;
   echo "\n";
}
// prints 
// \
// \\
```

If you are using this for directory separators, PHP has the build in constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`